# Cause creation of stored procedure to fail if referencing non-existant tables / columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, localdb

Given the following stored procedure definition

```
create procedure myproc
as

select * 
from sometablethatdoesnotexist

select somecolumnthatdoesnotexist 
from sometablethatdoesexist
```

Is it possible to configure sql-server (or localdb) to fail the creation of the stored procedure if at the time the stored procedure is created these objects do not exist? (either column or table)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but why do you need the database to prevent this? Are you letting users loose on your server to create procedures! Eeek! ;)

Comment: I have 10 years of cruft, if I remove a column from one of our 500 tables, I want to know which stored procedures are affected by it.  It's surprisingly difficult to determine which objects depend on a column reliably.

Comment: Have you looked at [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx)?

Comment: It is hard to determine column dependency *reliably*, but you can fake it half way by searching the object definitions in `sys.sql_modules`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yea, that's the thing that got me into this mess in the first place.  There are instances (that I cannot replicate) where `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` will not pick up a column reference.

Comment: @Matthew - I've used Red Gate's [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker) to find orphaned (or soon to be orphaned) entities in my databases. Their tools are not cheap but are excellent. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Red Gate in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

This is SQL Server's deferred name resolution.

[There is no way of turning it off](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127152/ability-to-disable-or-workaround-deferred-name-resolution). It will fail if you reference a non existent column on an existing table though.

Comment: Well looks like Connect item link is broken but I presume that is transient.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame they don't have the `SCHEMABINDING` option for sProcs.  Not that over-enthusiastic schema binding is any fun to deal with ...

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, the second part of your statement is good enough for me (as I'm only removing columns).  I'll accept when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this question, there is a hack as outlined by https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11635/geoff-patterson here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/is-there-a-way-to-force-deferred-name-resolution-even-if-the-table-exists-when-c

Here is his code sample - the temporary table is the key.

```
 --Say this table already exists.
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    a NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

--My C# code creates something like this
BEGIN TRAN 
GO

--the sproc gets generated first.
CREATE PROCEDURE mySproc
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #deferResolution (dummy INT NOT NULL)
    SELECT a,b FROM myTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #deferResolution WHERE 0=1)
END

--then the table update
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD b nvarchar(MAX)

COMMIT TRAN
```